# pip install opencv-python erro: 'NoneType' object is not iterable

Tags: python, ubuntu, pip, ubuntu-18.04, opencv

I am on Ubuntu 18.04.1 and try to install opencv-python as follows:

**pip install opencv-python**

But I get the following error:

```
Collecting opencv-python
Using cached opencv-python-4.3.0.38.tar.gz (88.0 MB)
Installing build dependencies ... done
Getting requirements to build wheel ... error
 ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: /usr/bin/python /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/_in_process.py get_requires_for_build_wheel /tmp/tmp91GW_M
   cwd: /tmp/pip-install-DcGggp/opencv-python
Complete output (22 lines):
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/_in_process.py", line 280, in <module>
  main()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/_in_process.py", line 263, in main
  json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/_in_process.py", line 114, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
  return hook(config_settings)
  File "/tmp/pip-build-env-hFz8RH/overlay/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 146, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
  return self._get_build_requires(config_settings, requirements=['wheel'])
  File "/tmp/pip-build-env-hFz8RH/overlay/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 127, in _get_build_requires
  self.run_setup()
  File "/tmp/pip-build-env-hFz8RH/overlay/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 243, in run_setup
  self).run_setup(setup_script=setup_script)
  File "/tmp/pip-build-env-hFz8RH/overlay/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 142, in run_setup
  exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'), locals())
  File "setup.py", line 448, in <module>
  main()
  File "setup.py", line 99, in main
  % {"ext": re.escape(sysconfig.get_config_var("EXT_SUFFIX"))}
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/re.py", line 210, in escape
  s = list(pattern)
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /usr/bin/python /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/_in_process.py get_requires_for_build_wheel /tmp/tmp91GW_M Check the logs for full command output.
```

What do I need to to to solve this?

Comment: try sudo apt install python3-opencv

Answer (score -2):

Use the below command:

```
sudo pip3 install opencv-python
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mYHwY.png)

Comment: **`WARNING: Running pip as the 'root' user can result in broken permissions and conflicting behaviour with the system package manager. It is recommended to use a virtual environment instead`**